# How to check a variable against Union type during runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, typechecking, union-types

I'm trying to write a function decorator that uses Python 3.6's type hints to check that a dictionary of arguments respects the type hints and if not raise an error with a clear description of the problem, to be used for HTTP APIs.

The problem is that when the function has a parameter using the `Union` type I can't check a variable against it at runtime.

For example, I have this function

```
from typing import Union
def bark(myname: str, descr: Union[int, str], mynum: int = 3) -> str:
    return descr + myname * mynum
```

I can do:

```
isinstance('Arnold', bark.__annotations__['myname'])
```

But not:

```
isinstance(3, bark.__annotations__['descr'])
```

Because `Union` cannot be used with `isinstance` or `issubclass`.

I couldn't find a way to check it using the type object.
I tried to implement the check by myself but while `bark.__annotations__['descr']` is shown as `typing.Union[int, str]` in the REPL I can't access the list of the types at runtime, if not using the ugly hack of examining `bark.__annotations__['descr'].__repr__()`.

Is there a proper way to access this information? Or is it deliberately intended to not be easily accessible at runtime?

Comment: Related: [How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?](//stackoverflow.com/q/48572831)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use the `__args__` attribute of `Union` which holds a `tuple` of the "possible contents:

```
>>> from typing import Union

>>> x = Union[int, str]
>>> x.__args__
(int, str)
>>> isinstance(3, x.__args__)
True
>>> isinstance('a', x.__args__)
True
```

The `__args__` argument is not documented so it could be considered "messing with implementation details" but it seems like a better way than parsing the `repr`.

Comment: Python 3.5 used `Union[int, str].__union_args__` instead, in 3.6 there seems no way to resolve `Union` from any other `Generic`, since `isinstance` fails :(

Answer (score 94):

In Python 3.8 and later, the approach suggested by [MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959000/3017652) and [Richard Xia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471187/3017652) can be improved by not using the undocumented attributes `__origin__` and `__args__`. This functionality is provided by the new functions [`typing.get_args(tp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) and [`typing.get_origin(tp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin):

```
>> from typing import Union, get_origin, get_args
>> x = Union[int, str]
>> get_origin(x), get_args(x)
(typing.Union, (<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>))
>> get_origin(x) is Union
True
>> isinstance(3, get_args(x))
True
>> isinstance('a', get_args(x))
True
>> isinstance([], get_args(x))
False
```

Comment: Just a side note - It's possible to import it from `typing_extensions` and it wil be working also on 3.7

Comment: Python 3.10 added the `int | str` syntax, where this solution no longer works. You can still use `get_origin`, but it will return `types.UnionType` rather than `typing.Union`. So a more general approach might be `get_origin(x) is typing.Union or get_origin(x) is types.UnionType`

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this same thing in Python 3.8 with the types themselves, rather than instances of the types?

Comment: Edit: I think running `issubclass` over the contents of `typing.get_args` might work.

Comment: A simpler version of @Gaberocksall's statement for python 3.10+ is `get_origin(x) in (Union, types.UnionType)`

Answer (score 25):

The existing accepted answer by MSeifert (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959000/7433423) does not distinguish `Union`s from other generic types, and it is difficult to determine at runtime whether a type annotation is a `Union` or some other generic type like `Mapping` due to the behavior of `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` on parameterized `Union` types.

It appears that generic types will have an undocumented `__origin__` attribute which will contain a reference to the original generic type used to create it. Once you have confirmed that the type annotation is a parameterized `Union`, you can then use the also undocumented `__args__` attribute to get the type parameters.

```py
>>> from typing import Union
>>> type_anno = Union[int, str]
>>> type_anno.__origin__ is Union
True
>>> isinstance(3, type_anno.__args__)
True
>>> isinstance('a', type_anno.__args__)
True
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `typeguard` module which can be installed with `pip`. It provides you with a function `check_argument_types` or a function decorator `@typechecked`. which should do your runtime type checking for you: https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard

```
from typing import Union
from typeguard import check_argument_types, typechecked

def check_and_do_stuff(a: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    check_argument_types() 
    # do stuff ...

@typechecked
def check_decorator(a: Union[str, int]) -> None:
    # do stuff ...

check_and_do_stuff("hello")
check_and_do_stuff(42)
check_and_do_stuff(3.14)  # raises TypeError
```

If you want to check a type of a single variable for a different reason, you can use typeguard's   `check_type` function directly:

```
from typing import Union
from typeguard import check_type

MyType = Union[str, int]

check_type("arg", "string", MyType, None)  # OK
check_type("arg", 42, MyType, None)  # OK
check_type("arg", 3.5, MyType, None)  # raises TypeError
```

The `"arg"` and `None` arguments are unused in this example.
Note that the `check_type` function is not documented as a public function of this module so its API may be subject to change.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that Union is not a type itself, but a description of a type.

But we can request the type simply by using `type(Union)`
(also works in 2.7)

```
>>> from typing import Union
>>> type(Union)
typing.Union
>>> x = Union[int, str]
>>> isinstance(x, type(Union))
True
```

Comment: This doesn't do the desired check - it should return `True` iff `x` is either an `int` or a `str`, not if `x` is a `Union` type object itself.