# Asking isinstance on a Union[...] type

Tags: python, types, mypy

I'm trying to ask an `isinstance` question on a user defined type: `ConstData = Union[int, str]`:

```
from typing import Union, Optional
ConstData = Union[int, str]
def foo(x) -> Optional[ConstData]:
    if isinstance(x, ConstData):  # <--- this doesn't work
    # if isinstance(x, (int, str)): <--- this DOES work ...
        return x
    return None
```

Sadly enough, it doesn't work:

```
$ mypy main.py
main.py:4: error: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
main.py:4: error: Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "object"; expected "Union[type, Tuple[Union[type, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957615/check-a-variable-against-union-type-at-runtime-in-python-3-6

Comment: @alex_noname thanks, it's indeed related. Still, with `if isinstance(x, get_args(ConstData)): return x` mypy can't infer that `x` has the correct return type. It complains it's `Any`

Comment: I think this will be possible when mypy adds support of new style Union from PEP 604 in isinstance https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About:

"Still, with `if isinstance(x, get_args(ConstData)): return x` mypy can't infer that `x` has the correct return type. It complains it's `Any`"

I think it is a bug in `reveal_type()`, Mypy undertands the narrowing of `x` type. As you can see in the following code, it does not raise an error when `test()` is called with `x`:

```
def test(k:Union[int, str]) -> None:
    pass


def foo(x: Any) -> Optional[ConstData]:
    if isinstance(x, get_args(ConstData)):
        reveal_type(x)  # Mypy: Revealed type is "Any"
        test(x)  # Mypy: no error
        return x  # Mypy: no error
    return None
```

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: `get_args` is not valid in this context: if you change the `foo(x: Any)` signature with foo(x: Optional[ConstData]), then `test(x)` show the mypy error: `Mypy: Argument 1 to "test" has incompatible type "Union[int, str, None]"; expected "Union[int, str]"`. This means that `None` type has not been removed by `isinstance`.

Answer (score -2):

It can be checked with ConstData.**origin**._name == 'Union'