# Type alias with union

Tags: python

I currently have this type alias, and some associated functions in my code:

```py
Constant = int

def operation(data: Union[Constant, OtherTypes]):
    if isinstance(data, Constant):
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Now, I would like for `Constant` to also represent another type, say float. This Constant alias is used throughout my codebase, so I'd like to not have to change it everywhere.

I have tried:

```py
Constant = (int, float)
```

This works nicely with `isinstance`, but the `Union`s complain that `"TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type."`

I have then tried:

```py
Constant = Union[int, float]
```

Now, the issues come with the `isinstance`; I get `"TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks"`.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to achieve ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Pankkake in their answer, for Python 3.10 you can simply do `Constant = int | float` and it will work everywhere.

However, if you must support older versions of Python, you can use the solutions provided in [Check a variable against Union type at runtime in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957615/check-a-variable-against-union-type-at-runtime-in-python-3-6) by Frank, MSeifert and Richard Xia:

### Python 3.8+

Use the [typing.get_args(tp)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) function to get a tuple with the union types, which you can use inside `isinstance`:

```py
from typing import Union, get_args

Constant = Union[int, float]

def operation(data: Union[Constant, OtherTypes]):
    if isinstance(data, get_args(Constant)):
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

`get_args` only returns the type's arguments without validating if the type is an `Union` or other generic type, which seems enough for your requirement.

If for some reason you also need to check at runtime if the `Constant` type is an `Union` specifically, use the [typing.get_origin(tp)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) function:

```py
from typing import Union, get_origin

if get_origin(Constant) is Union:
    # do something
```

### Python 3.5.3+

Before 3.8 the `get_args` and `get_origin` functions didn't exist, so you needed to use the undocumented attributes `__args__` and `__origin__` instead.

```py
def operation(data: Union[Constant, OtherTypes]):
    if isinstance(data, Constant.__args__):
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

This still works for 3.10.5 but, since these attributes are undocumented, the snippet above could stop working with no short notice in any future Python version.

### Python 3.5.0 to 3.5.2

Type hints were implemented in Python's 3.5.0 version. Up to 3.5.2 the attribute name to get an union's arguments was `__union_params__`:

```py
def operation(data: Union[Constant, OtherTypes]):
    if isinstance(data, Constant.__union_params__):
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else
```

Of course, this attribute only exists for `Union` types, so if you need to check if a type is an `Union`, check for the existence of the attribute.

Note that this only works up to Python 3.5.2, since in 3.5.3 they changed the attribute name to `__args__`.

Answer (score 2):

`isinstance` supporting `Union`s comes with python 3.10 . As such, starting from that version, the second solution will work.

See https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/ .

Comment: I still wonder if it's possible to solve this problem with prior versions of Python.

Comment: This is a special case, in general, `isinstance` will *not work with type annotations*, only with *actual types*